# Get the local IP address associated to a local MAC address

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, ip-address, mac-address

In a `.properties` file I store the local network interface (i.e. MAC address) which I want to be used by my Java application. Then I get that information as a property.

Now I want to get the local IP address currently associated to this MAC address. How could I do that with Java?

Note that I can't use Reverse ARP on a gateway. I don't have any gateway, I work locally only.

Thanks.

Comment: try this Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()

Comment: Why? Why not just store the IP address?

Comment: @EJP Because my users change regularly the IP address and I don't want to force them to update it in my app. But thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NetworkInterface for  this (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html):

```
  Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces =
                    NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
  while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
    NetworkInterface i = interfaces.nextElement();
    if ( i.getHardwareAddress().... ) {
    }

  }
```